# HTML every nth iteration with a twist--the nth changes every xth time using array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration

Everyone knows how to output a bit of html every nth iteration in a foreach loop.

```
$i=0;
foreach($info as $key){
    if($i%3 == 0) {
      echo $i > 0 ? "</div>" : ""; // close div if it's not the first
      echo "<div>";
    }
    //do stuff
$i++;
}
```

I'm trying to do this same thing, but instead of a known value for $i, I'm pulling values in from an array like

```
Array(0=>2, 1=>1, 2=>5)
```

so that instead of

```
<div>
  item
  item
  item
</div>
<div>
  item
  item
  item
</div>
<div>
  item
  item
  item
</div>
```

I can get something like this:

```
<div>
  item
  item
</div>
<div>
  item
</div>
<div>
  item
  item
  item
  item
  item
</div>
```

But I just can't get it to work. I think I'm close, but something's just escaping me. Any ideas?

Here's the code I'm running right now:

```
//$footnote = array of values
$i=0;
$m=0;
$bridge .= '<div class="grid block menu">';
    foreach($value['sections'] as $section) {

        if ($i++%$footnote[$m] === 0) { 
            $bridge .= '</div><div class="grid block menu">';
            $m++;
        }
        $secname = $section['name'];
        $dishcount = count($section['items']); 

        $bridge .= '<h3>'. $secname .' '.$footnote[0].'</h3>';

         $i++;  
    } //end section foreach
$bridge .= '</div>';
```

Comment: What's the name of the sections array? Exactly what data do you want for each item?

Comment: It's commented out  as $footnote, hence the $footnote[$m] used in the modulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is in the `if($i++%...)` section of your code.

Instead of incrementing `$i` and checking the result of the modular expression, just check if `$i == $footnote[$m]` and then reset `$i` back to 0 when it is a success.

I modified your script a little locally, try this out:

```php
$i = $m = 0;

$bridge .= '<div class="grid block menu">';

foreach($value['sections'] as $section)
{
    if ($i == $footnote[$m])
    { 
        $bridge .= '</div><div class="grid block menu">';
        $m++;
        $i = 0;
    }
    $secname = $section['name'];
    $dishcount = count($section['items']);

    $bridge .= '<h3>'. $secname .' '.$footnote[$m].'</h3>';

    $i++;
}

$bridge .= '</div>';
```

This way, you are actually iterating through each footnote instead of just checking to see if it is divisible by the number specified.

Comment: Brilliant. And a simple two line code change to boot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Untested code, let me know if any changes are necessary so I can update the answer appropriately.

```
// Calculate section breaks
$sections = [ 2, 1, 5];
$sectionBreaks = [];
$sum = 0;
foreach ($sections as $section) {
    $sum += $section;
    $sectionBreaks[] = $sum;
}
// Add the items to each section
$results = [];
$result = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (array_search($i, $sectionBreaks) !== false) {
        $results[] = $result;
        $result = '';
    }
    $result .= '<h3>' . $item . '</h3>';
}
// Collapse it all together
$finalResult = '<div>' . implode('</div><div>', $results) . '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I think the answer I selected does a slightly better job of achieving correct output utilizing my original code (I only had to change two lines). I haven't tested yours, but it definitely could be useful in another scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to loop thru data in order to achieve the example you exposed at first. `foreach` and `for`. This works, but unless you give us some data to work with I wont be able to adjust it to it.

```
$bridge='';
foreach($value['sections'] as $section) {
    $bridge .= '<div class="grid block menu" number="'.$section.'"><h3>MY TITLE!! '. $section['name'] .'</h3>';     
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $section; $x++) {
        $bridge .= "Here goes the content; Item $x<br>";
    }
    $bridge .= '</div>';
}
echo $bridge;
```

I hope it helps :)